# how to resolve error executing ddl commands in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Hi I am new to spring Boot and i created new project(Demo) using spring initilizr Project structure is Project : Maven Project Language : Java Spring Boot : 2.4.2

application.propertites file is like

```
server.port=8084   
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb  
spring.datasource.username=postgres spring.datasource.password=root 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update   
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true   
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

I have Created some classes and controllers :

Entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Service :

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public ResponseEntity addUser(JsonNode userData) {
        User user  = objectMapper.convertValue(userData, User.class);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userData);
    }
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/adduser")
    public ResponseEntity addUser(@RequestBody JsonNode userData){
        return userService.addUser(userData);
    }
}
```

But when i run the program i got error related to DB command : DLL command syntax error
as i am new to this framework i am not sure why this error is ? here are logs i am getting
error logs :

```
2021-02-10 12:09:55.296  WARN 14681 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id int4 not null, email varchar(255), user_name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id int4 not null, email varchar(255), user_name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.note.noteShare.NoteShareApplication.main(NoteShareApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 14
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user` is a [reserved keyword in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Change your table name to something else, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
```

Comment: this was also the rootcause of my error using H2